# How do data checksums interact with streaming replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.3, checksum

[Data checksums](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.3#Data_Checksums) are a new feature introduced in 9.3, and:

> there is a new GUC parameter "ignore_checksum_failure" which will force PostgreSQL to continue processing a transaction even if corruption is detected

In the event of a checksum failure on a replication master, will that corrupt data replicate to slaves or will replication halt. Does it depend on the setting of `ignore_checksum_failure`?

[This](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/backend/storage/page/README;hb=HEAD) README has some useful related information but doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: Very good question. Depends partly on whether data checksums affect WAL as well (which IIRC they don't, except for full page images in WAL). I haven't had time to dig into data checksums as I've been helping with other features. Asking on pgsql-general may be a good idea. If time and new baby permits I will take a look at the sources, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: @Craig congratulations!

Comment: The things you learn on StackExchange... "been helping with other features" is a euphemism for "changing diapers".

Answer (score 1):

If the data was corrupted while on disk, the corruption should not get replicated unless it was already present in the backup from which the replica was created.

Of course if you ignore checksum failures then the master may start going wrong things, and that wrongness will be replicated.

If the corruption is occurring in memory then all bets are off.

Comment: is pretty close to the mark here. The documentation on the `ignore_checksum_failure` parameter includes the warning that "this behavior may ... propagate ... corruption". Without explicitly mentioning (streaming) replication, it would seem that this is implied here. Normally a checksum error would cause the transaction to abort, so no data would be replicated. Ignoring this error would allow you to commit the transaction and write (potentially) corrupted data, which would also be replicated.